# Report progress inside for loop

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am calling this code inside a for loop and I need to do this since progress depends on this for loop value.

```
bgworker1.ReportProgress(k * count);
```

But I receive an exception:

`this operation has already had operation completed called on it and further calls are illegal`

How can I solve this??

Edit:

```
private void bgworker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
 for (k = 1; k <= tcount; k++)
 {
  bgworker1.ReportProgress(k * count);
 }
}

private void bgworker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

private void bgworker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        bgworker1.ReportProgress(k * count);
    }
```

Comment: please check, if this can not solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812725/method-accessed-by-more-than-one-thread-in-c-sharp-using-progressbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can tackle this is reporting progress in a exclusive for-loop for this only task, like this

```
private void bgworker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            //Insert your logic HERE
            worker.ReportProgress(i * 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you suggesting like reportprogress should be called in bgworker_dowork()?

Comment: that's right. The worker that reports progress in this case is not the bgworker per se. I use this to report progress on reports in which Q of records is dynamic and large.

Comment: If this method was useful, please don't forget to mark as answer

Comment: Sure..I will do..but how can I call this bgworker_dowork() where needed?

I mean this will be another function. I want this to be executed inside another function? Can I makeup the solution like that?

Comment: Could you please show your bgworker1_DoWork and bgworker1_ProgressChanged and bgworker1_RunWorkerCompleted methods??

Comment: Some observations:

-You're reporting progress on RunWorkerCompleted. This is what gets you the exception in your question. RunWorkerCompleted executes when the BackGroundWorker has done its job, and hence, has been disposed of. You can change that line with something like this


   (( progressbar1.Value = 100; //In case where your maximum value  for progressbar is 100 ))



With that your methods should should work.

Comment: -The approach I gave with the solution I handed was to leave bgworker1.ReportProgress out of the DoWork method. This is because in order to use ReportProgress you gotta have the knowledge of the Q of steps your bgworker1 will do, and in most of cases that is complicated, especially in the case where you make querys and operations on a set of records from a database, because the Q of records returned can be different every time. However if you know certainly well how many steps your bgworker will do, your method should suffice.

Comment: The approach I gave with the solution I handed was to leave bgworker1.ReportProgress out of the DoWork method.

If so, then what will be the content in DoWork method?

I hope you know how I am trying to do..I have some tasks in another function and when this task gets executed I need to show progress..

Am I doing the right thing, for achieving this?

Comment: The content would be the answer I handed plus your code on the "else" block, just before "worker.ReportProgress(i*1)".

Comment: Thanks shingonati0n...
:)